# Is there a way to convert from byte[] to long[]

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am working on an android application. I was using a static function in a library, that takes `byte[]` as a parameter.

I used to pass a hard code byte array containing 36 bytes:

```
new byte[]{-13, 35, -92, -79, 47, -51, -57, 39, ......};
```

But in the latest release, they changed the function to take a `long[]` instead. So I can no longer pass my byte array.

How can I convert from my saved byte[] to a long[] in order to still use this function with the same value as before?

Is there a conversion from `byte[]` to `long[]` ? To my knowledge 'byte[]' can be converted to `long` but not to long array.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated

Comment: Well you can always widen. so just simply transfer it to a long array?

Comment: apparently if I just transfer it to a long array, the value changes. Because the function will stop behaving correctly. Problem is I don't have visibility to the Library, and their support take ages to respond

Comment: It's not clear exactly which library you're using or its semantics. Is it the case that each `long` in the array corresponds to eight bytes in the previous version? Or one-to-one?

Comment: Does it work if you change `new byte[]` to `new long[]`?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious here but you said the byte[] array is hardcoded in, why don't you just hardcode in a long[] array? So using new long[] instead?

Comment: Your problem is likely due to sign-extension that occurs when widening.  Since you hard-coded the values in the first place, just change your hard-coded data.

Comment: @Austin yes I want to hard code the long array. But I don't know how to get the corresponding long array values

Comment: @Youssef I don't understand. You said you hardcoded in the values. Why can't you use the same values in a long array?

Comment: @Austin I tried that, but that is making the function stop working. So My question was more, how to get a long[] array that has the exact same output (memory wise) as the byte array

Comment: @Youssef, without knowing what the function is I don't think we will be able to answer. It sounds like the function must have changed quite a bit.

Comment: @Youssef this is a good time to learn how signed and unsigned integers are represented in binary. A byte is 8 bits, and in Java is always signed. So `-13` is the same as `0xF3`, but the compiler will warn you about loss of precision because the largest number a signed byte can represent is 127 (or 0x7F). In a Java long, `-13` is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF3`. But a long can represent `0xF3` (`243`) without overflowing and becoming negative. See also [`Byte.toUnsignedLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedLong-byte-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you will need to convert 4 bytes to one long. So the most simple solution would be using ByteBuffers.

```
long[] byteToLong(byte[] array) {
     ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(array);
     LongBuffer longBuffer = byteBuffer.asLongBuffer();
     long[] result = new long[longBuffer.capacity()];
     longBuffer.get(result);
     return result;
}
```

Note: this produces BigEndian values - not sure what your API needs.

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the simplest question you should have tried it id IDE.

```
    byte[] bytesArr = { 0, 6, 36, -84, 113, 125, -118, -47 };
    long[] longArr = new long[bytesArr.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < bytesArr.length; i++) {
        longArr[i] = bytesArr[i];
    }
```

**Also, it is possible to convert long[] to byte[] but you will loose all values which are not in range of byte i.e. -128 to 127.**